# Using xcode5 svn or git

Tags: xcode

I am learning git and SVN in Xcode 5.
My question:
How should I revert back my previous commit when I commit my code?
Is there a way on a branch to revert back to previous commits?

For example, I commit a state, call it GOODSPOT, then I commit, a few times as my code progresses. Can I easily revert back to GOODSPOT, in a single click ? Or do i have to go through line by line. Similar to going back to an old snap shot ?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html

Comment: Historically Xcode version control has always been limited/spotty. I can't say how it is recently, because I haven't looked back since I started using SourceTree (an awesome GUI app for git/mercurial), and now I use Xcode only for coding. I am very command-line phobic and failed several times at learning git in the past, but this time it was different. Just my $0.02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
$ git push origin (branch)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go back to any commit you want to. Use the command-line interface (also known as Terminal).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned every time i try Source Control. It depends on whether you are working with people. I would just go back to the terminal and recommend it.

For versioning in Xcode, I do this:
- in my Developer directory I set up a project folder
- then Duplicate the Outer initial folder Xcode sets up and append its name with a number and two word description of where it's at
- this also duplicates development art, research notes etc
- the inner folder is all XCode cares about, so that one gets untouched
- when the finished app ships,  I illustrate its development for proving copyright originality